# Django: @login_required decorator does not redirect to "next"

Tags: python, django, authentication, decorator

I am building a dictionary app using Django where users are able to define words. However, I want users to be logged in before being able to do that.

I am trying to implement this constraint using the build-in `@login_required` decorator on my `define` view (the view that lets users define words).

Using `@login_required`, when I am not logged in and try to define a word (using a definition form) I correctly get redirected to the login page.

Here is my `login_view` view in **views.py**:

```
def login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
        password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL))
    return render(request, "users/login.html", {"form": form})
```

At this time my URL looks something like:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/login?next=/define

So far so good. As soon as I log in, however, Django does not redirect me back to the definition form I was trying to access in the first place (located at /define). How can I tell Django to redirect me to the definition form in this situation?

Also, in my **settings.py** I have redefined the `LOGIN_URL`, `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, and `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` variables as follows:

```
LOGIN_URL = "users:login"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "dictionary:index"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "dictionary:index"
```

where `users` is the name of the app that handles logins and `dictionary` is the name of the app that handles definitions.

Might the problem lie in one of these variables?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can undo the changes in your settings and change the line

```
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL))
```

to         `return redirect('/targeturl')`